# Adding a share in a Failover Cluster with quotas enabled takes 10 minutes

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster

I have File Service cluster where one of the file server resources is hosting ~50,000 user home directories. The home directories do have a quota template assigned through the [FSRM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732431.aspx).

When trying to add a new share using the Failover Cluster Manager's *"Add File Share"* wizard, it starts by retrieving all quotas on all shared folders over all defined file server cluster resources. Which is taking ~10 minutes in this environment.

How could I either

- speed up the process of quota enumeration
- limit the quota enumeration process to just a single file server cluster resource
- disable the quota enumeration completely for the *New Share* Wizard

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally worked around the problem by lifting the requirement to use the GUI for file share creation entirely. Instead, I documented the use of New-SmbShare as the share creation procedure. Adding shares in this way bypasses all pre-configuration checks the GUI wizard is performing, including the quota enumeration.

```
New-SmbShare -Name <ShareName> -ScopeName "<CAPName>" -Path "<LocalDirectoryToBeShared>" -FullAccess "Everyone" -Description "<Comment>"
```

The [`New-SmbShare` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635722(v=wps.630).aspx) has been introduced with Server 2012 R2 / Windows 8.1. For previous (2012, 2008R2, 2008) version File Server clusters, you can borrow the `NativeMethods` class with which is importing the [NetShareAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525384(v=vs.85).aspx) function from Netapi32.dll from [a script](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-00-73-13/3750.share.txt) published along with an [MSDN blog post about shares in Fileover Cluster scopes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2010/07/09/10036201.aspx).

My significantly shortened version looks like this:

```
#Using Win32 API NetShareAdd via p/invoke to be able to specify the scope in SHARE_INFO_503
$signature = @"

    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Collections;

    public class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("Netapi32.dll")]
        public static extern uint NetShareAdd([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string strServer, Int32 dwLevel, ref SHARE_INFO_503 buf, out uint parm_err);

        [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR {
            public byte revision;
            public byte size;
            public short control;
            public IntPtr owner;
            public IntPtr group;
            public IntPtr sacl;
            public IntPtr dacl;
        }

        public enum SHARE_TYPE : uint
        {
            STYPE_DISKTREE = 0,
            STYPE_PRINTQ = 1,
            STYPE_DEVICE = 2,
            STYPE_IPC = 3,
            STYPE_SPECIAL = 0x80000000
        };

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct SHARE_INFO_503
        {
            public string shi503_netname;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public SHARE_TYPE shi503_type;
            public string shi503_remark;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public int shi503_permissions;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public int shi503_max_uses;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public int shi503_current_uses;
            public string shi503_path;
            public string shi503_passwd;
            public string shi503_servername;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public int shi503_reserved;
            public IntPtr shi503_security_descriptor;
        }


        public static uint ShareFolder(string servername, string sharename, string path, string remark)
        {
            SHARE_INFO_503 shInfo = new SHARE_INFO_503();
            shInfo.shi503_netname = sharename;
            shInfo.shi503_type = SHARE_TYPE.STYPE_DISKTREE;
            shInfo.shi503_remark = remark;
            shInfo.shi503_permissions = 0;
            shInfo.shi503_max_uses = -1;
            shInfo.shi503_current_uses = 0;
            shInfo.shi503_path = path;
            shInfo.shi503_passwd = null;
            shInfo.shi503_servername = servername;
            shInfo.shi503_reserved = 0;
            shInfo.shi503_security_descriptor = IntPtr.Zero;

            uint nRetValue = 0;
            uint param_err = 0;

            nRetValue = NetShareAdd(servername, 503, ref shInfo, out param_err);

            //Console.WriteLine("Sharing " + path + " on " + servername + " as " + sharename + " returned " + nRetValue + " (" + param_err+ ")");

            return nRetValue;
        }
    }
"@


#Import the FailoverClusters PowerShell module if it is not already imported
Import-Module FailoverClusters

#Add the function type that will be used to share the folder in the defined scope
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $signature
```

Usage is trivial:

```
[NativeMethods]::ShareFolder("<CAPname>", "<ShareName>", "<LocalDirectoryToBeShared>", "<Comment>")
```

The `ShareFolder` function returns 0 upon successful execution and finishes instantly, even with quotas enabled. To be run on one of the cluster nodes hosting the CAP / file server resource. You might have to fix share ACLs afterwards, as the default share creation ACL is just `Everyone:Read` and cannot be specified with this method.